# How to write a spec for a model called Test using rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, model

When trying to write a spec for a model called `Test`, I get conflicted with `Test:Module`.

Here is my code:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Test, :type => :model do

  before { @test = Test.new(title: "Sample Test", description: "Description of sample test")   }
  subject { @test }

  it { should respond_to(:title)}
  it { should respond_to(:description)}

end
```

And I’m getting the error

```
   undefined method `new' for Test:Module
```

If anyone knows how to write this properly, thanks.

Comment: I think, if you go this route, this may not be your last obstacle. I tried to reproduce it by running `rails generate scaffold Test title:string description:string`, but Rails refused it with the message `The name 'Test' is either already used in your application or reserved by Ruby on Rails. Please choose an alternative and run this generator again.`

Comment: Using "Test" as a model name may be a bad idea. It may conflict with reserved words in Ruby or in Rails.

Comment: Thanks, I will use an alternative name like "Teste"

Answer (score 0):

You may explicitly reference the `Test` constant of your external namespace by referencing it as ::Test. It otherwise matches a Rspec related `Test` module.